# What is the jQuery's equivalent of dojo's marginBox()?

Tags: jquery, dojo

Dojo has marginBox function:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/marginBox.html.

What is the jQuery's equivalent of that function?

Comment: I don't know dojo but in native DOM API, it looks quite similar to [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method except than it is relative to viewport, not any non static parent element. For this you have `element.offsetLeft` and `element.offsetTop` which are quite the same result as using jQuery `position()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use several of jQuery's functions to get the information you need.

```js
console.log("Width: " + $('#a1').outerWidth(true));
console.log("Height: " + $('#a1').outerHeight(true));
console.log("Top: " + $('#a1').position().top);
console.log("Left: " + $('#a1').position().left);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#a1 {
  width: 250px;
  height:  150px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<div id="a1">
  This is a div with margin, padding and border
</div>
```